# Share dropbox storage from iOS app?

Tags: ios4, cloud, storage, dropbox

Dropbox provides SDK for iOS developer to upload/download files via dropbox.

I am new to this and hope to clear some understanding.

If user want to use this service,he must login in with dropbox account. That means it is not possible for multiple users ( maybe more than hundreds ) to use the same dropbox account with this iOS app. Is that correct ?

If enable hundreds users to share central storage,what are the mature cloud service for iOS developers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drop box allows users from different accounts to share folders.  Looking through the documentation there seems to be no way to share a folder with a user via the API.  If I find out differently I will report back.  I am trying to do the same and feel I will have to screen scrape the website.